# Chrome + Ad Blocker hides the content of the post

Tags: posts

I would like some help with a problem i'm having with my Wordpress Site. Users that have Ad blocker active and the latest version of Chrome seems that they are seeing our posts as blanks.

Specifically, they can see every part of the website pretty much, expect ads (of course) and the content of the posts.

The link to my website is: http://www.4gamers.gr/

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I am using the latest version of chrome and adBlocker, i didn't notice any problem visiting your website.

Comment: Did you browse through different posts? Like this one for example: http://www.4gamers.gr/gta-v-75-million-units-shipped/

Comment: Yes i just checked your latest link. Only 2 blocks on the page, the post content (which i can't read) is shown. Do you see the block notification yourself?

Comment: I have repeatedly tried to reproduce the bug on my part (cleared cache, enabled different ad blockers etc) but i can't. Some users though seem to have this problem and i'm really confused to be honest.

According to them, when they disable the Ad Blocker or put our website into their whitelist, they can see the content of the posts perfectly fine.